# Solving a differential equation $y''+2y'=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I've been stuck on this equation.

$y''+2y'=0$ is fairly simple, the general solution comes out as $y=c_{1}+c_{2}e^{-2x}$.

But when I try to solve the particular equation including the $x$ on the right I get stuck lacking a variable or like another equation. By the guessing method:

$y_{s} = Ax+B$,
$y'_{s} = A$,
$y''_{s} = 0$

Which leaves me with

$y_{s} = \frac{x}{2}+B$

Is there any other way to solve it or can it not be solved and the variable $B$ will  be stuck there until I get some sort of more information / another equation or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your solution doesn’t work is because this is a “failure case” - that is to say that the usual particular integral is not independent of the complementary function, due to the appearance of the constant term in both.

Instead of using $y=Ax+B$ as the particular integral you have to use instead $$y=Ax^2+Bx$$
$$\implies y’=2Ax+B\implies y’’=2A$$

And then, $$2A+4Ax+2B=x\implies A=\frac14, B=-\frac14$$

Now you can write out the complete solution.

Comment: How did you arrive at that answer? There's only one expression and two variables which are unknown, how did you calculate A and B in the last step?

Comment: It’s an identity which must be true for all values of $x$ so you just compare coefficients of $x$ and of constant terms

Comment: English is not my first language so I'm having a hard time undestanding the mathematical terms, is there any way you could show it more in depth?

Comment: @Cody. May I ask what's your first language?

Comment: @Cody what mathematical terms do you not understand?

Comment: @md2perpe don't see how that's relevant but sure, it's polish

Comment: @DavidQuinn I just don't understand how you calculate the A and Bs without just guessing them

Comment: Coefficients of $x\implies 4A=1$, and coefficients of $x^0\implies B=-A$

Comment: @DavidQuinn okay that helped out a ton, I get it now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Cody. Your first language is of course not relevant for the mathematical problem, but can help when someone wants to explain things that you don't understand because of English not being your first language. _Dobranoc!_

Comment: @md2perpe maybe it would be but using english and somehow simplifying the language or showing it graphically will help others instead of locking it behind a language barier. Let's help others who find this thread next ;)

Answer (score 3):

$y''+2y'=x$ can be solved directly. Start with an integrating factor of $e^{2x}$:
$$
       e^{2x}(y''+2y')=xe^{2x} \\
          \frac{d}{dx}(e^{2x}y')=xe^{2x} \\
            e^{2x}y' = \int xe^{2x}dx=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x-\int\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}dx=\frac{1}{2}xe^{2x}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}+C \\
       y'=\frac{1}{4}(2x-1)+Ce^{-2x} \\
       y = \frac{1}{4}(x^2-x)-\frac{C}{2}e^{-2x}+D.
$$
It's easy to check this $y$ is a solution:
$$
     y''=\frac{1}{2}-2Ce^{-2x} \\
     2y'=\frac{1}{2}(2x-1)+2Ce^{-2x} \\
     y''+2y'=x
$$

Comment: Notice that I derived the general solution, with no guesses. And I verified that the solution is, indeed, a solution. It pays to approach this systematically, rather than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+2y'=x$$
Integrate:
$$y'+2y=\dfrac 12x^2+C$$
Try to solve with:
$$y_p=Ax^2+Bx+c$$